# Product API - how to access big databases of product - best approach?

Tags: api-design

I am thinking of a project that requires access to a huge amount of product data - i.e. when you type in the product name it would return a page with the product image, name, brand etc.

I would not be selling those items, just displaying the metadata and direct to the sellers.

My question is how this can be achieved:

1. Would sourcing data from places like Amazon Product API and Google Merchant Center, Walmart, BestBuy, Argos etc. be possible at all or they keep all their product data for themselves?
2. How complex would be a seeding my database by a merchant in case they want to sync their product database with mine (but they don't sell on places like Amazon).
3. Is scraping websites for the product information allowed or it depends on the terms of use of the website.

I am slightly confused on what are the possible approaches.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm all for idea brainstorming, but there is a ton of research you could have done prior to asking this question. Asking these questions without having researched at all, is not indicative of someone able to complete this project.

1. Amazon does have an API called the product advertising API, but it requires an Amazon associate account which requires you to drive sales to products because it is an affiliate marketing program. The product advertising API is also limited in requests based on your associate account performance. Walmart has a public API. BestBuy has an API. Target has a sort of under the radar api point but very little documentation.
2. This question is too vague. What exactly do you foresee being complicated? What kind of db? What type of environment aka how is your db(s) structured?
3. In the US scraping has been deemed legal. For a long time it was a gray area. Websites like Amazon will still block you. There are ways to circumvent scraper blocking, but it will likely cost you money.  You could use proxies or pay for the data from companies that have already procured this data.

There are already services that do this by the way. Helium 10 is an example for Amazon.